# Prove that $ B=\{(a,b):a<b\} \cup \{\{x\}:x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\} $ is a base for $M$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X= \mathbb{R} $ and $ \tau_M=\{U \cup F : U $ is open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R} $ and $ F \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} $. This is called the Michael line denoted by $M$. Prove that $ B=\{(a,b):a<b\} \cup \{\{x\}:x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\} $ is a base for $M$

I don't have a clue where to start. Seems incredibly obvious that this is true but I don't see any difference between this definition of the base and the definition of the michael line. They seem almost identical. My only thought is $\forall~ U\in X,~ \exists ~(a,b) \subset U$ which is an open subset and $\{\{x\}:x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\} \subset F$ which is also an open subset and $ B=\{(a,b):a<b\} \cup \{\{x\}:x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\} \subset U \cup F$ and $B$ is open since it is the union of open sets.

Answer (score 1):

If $O$ is open in $M$, by definition it is of the form $U \cup F$, where $U$ is a usual open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $F \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Now, in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, the set of rational open intervals is a base for the topology (standard fact) and so we can find $(p_n, q_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where all $p_n,q_n$ are rationals, such that $U = \cup_n (p_n, q_n)$. And clearly $F$ can be written as the union of its singletons: $F = \cup_{x \in F} \{x\}$.

So $O = \cup_n (a_n, b_n) \cup \cup_{x \in F} \{x\}$, so we have written $O$ as a union of open rational intervals and irrational singletons, exactly as needed.

The only observations are that the rational intervals form a base for the usual reals, and every set is the union of its singletons.

Comment: what is the purpose of n? just to denote that it's a union of a countable number of distinct intervals?

Comment: @chris Yes, it could be any index set really, but there are only countably many such intervals in total anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you have to prove that each open set of $M$ (member of $\tau_M$) *can be written as a union* of members of the base $B$.

Comment: Isn't that obvious though? Isn't B basically just the definition of the michaels line slightly reworded?

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint above this can be done since: Open sets or member of $\tau_M$ look like $(a,b) \cup \{x\}$ for $\{x\} \in F$ and $(a,b)$ open in the usual topology. Well if $\{x\} \in (a,b)$ we're done. If $x$ is not in $(a,b)$ then $x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ (I probably should say $F$ here, but $F$ is a subset so it's okay) $\Rightarrow (a,b) \cup \{x\}$ is open in $B$ (by definition of $\tau_M$ being the union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $F\subset \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still kinda in the same position. I don't know why, but it seems to me like that is just a rephrased definition of the michaels line and I don't really get how that proves it is a base. although I don't understand why it needs to be proven that it is a base when it seems indistinguishable from the definition of the michaels line. I don't know what I'm missing here.